# Remove non-numeric characters within parantheses

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am looking to remove the non-numeric characters within a certain parentheses, and remove ***other*** parentheses in that line. Look below for an example;

```r
text <- c("1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 (WSO) (89021-design)
John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)",
          "1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 ASP (890212-wso)
John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
Other Stuff",
          "1110383 Project something SD (890212)
John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)")
```

The expected output would be:

```r
cat(paste0(myoutxt, collapse = "\n"))
# 1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 WSO (89021)
# John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
# 1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 ASP (890212)
# John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
# 1110383 Project something SD (890212)
# John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
```

I came up with a regex that matches my 5 or 6 digit number, but I am not sure what should be the replacement. Also I think the following should be modified since it doesn't consider possible presence of other parentheses to remove them.

```regex
^.*?\\([^\\d]*(\\d{5,6})[^\\d]*\\).*$
```

#### *Logic:*

Basically, I am looking to find the line with a 5-6 digit number (e.g. `89021` or `890212`) between parentheses. Then, if there are other stuff within that parentheses, I want to remove them (e.g. `-design` or `-wso`). And lastly, if there are other parentheses in that specific line (e.g. `(WSO)`) I want the parentheses, and not the word, to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about substituting

```regex
(?:\(([^)\d]+)\)(.*?))?\([^\d)]*(\d{5,6})[^\d)]*\)
```

to

```regex
$1$2($3)
```

- `(?:\(([^)\d]+)\)(.*?))?` the first [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) part [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) any preceding parenthesized stuff to `$1`. Anything that might follow before the parenthesized 5-6 digit part is captured to `$2`
- `\([^\d)]*(\d{5,6})[^\d)]*\)` the second part captures the 5-6 digits to `$3`

[See the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/C1Dflp/4)

---

In [r](/questions/tagged/r) using `gsub`:

```r
gsub(pattern='(?:\\(([^)\\d]+)\\)(.*?))?\\([^\\d)(]*(\\d{5,6})[^\\d)(]*\\)', 
         replacement='\\1\\2(\\3)', 
         x=text, 
         perl=TRUE, fixed = FALSE)
```

Comment: Close, but not taking care of other parentheses in the line (i.e. replace `(WSO)` with `WSO`). Also, I prefer to not assume that my 5-6 digit number would always come right after the parenthesis. That's why I have ```\([^\d]*...``` in ```\([^\d]*(\d{5,6})[^\d]*\)```. P.S. Cheers +1.

Comment: I tried to explain it in the logic part. Here I try again; I find the line which has a 5-6 digit number between parentheses. I remove anything else between parentheses except that number. **At the same line**, if there is another set of parentheses, I want them removed. In my sample text, it would be removing parentheses around `(WSO)` in the first entry. Compare expected output to sample data. p.s. If I use your suggestion in the comment (now deleted), then `($1)` for replacement won't work.

Comment: I understood already, haven't read question attentive enough. Try [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/C1Dflp/3) and replace with `$1$2($3)`. If it works for you, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

1. `"\\(([^0-9@]*)\\)"`: Remove parentheses from anything that doesn't contain a number or `@`
2. `"\\((\\d{5,6}).*\\)"`: For parentheses containing 5 to 6 numbers + anything else, leave only the numbers.

I assumed the other set of parentheses would always contain email addresses.

```
library(stringr)

cat(
  paste0(
    str_replace(
      str_replace(text, "\\(([^0-9@]*)\\)", "\\1"), 
      "\\((\\d{5,6}).*\\)", 
      "\\1"), 
    collapse = "\n"
  )
)

# 1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 WSO (89021)
# John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
# 1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 ASP (890212)
# John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
# Other Stuff
# 1110383 Project something SD (890212)
# John Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lateral approach

```
fun_0 <- function(string) {
  vec <- strsplit(string, '\\(|\\)', perl = TRUE)[[1L]]
  s <- ifelse(startsWith(string, '('), 1L, 2L)
  e <- length(vec)
  if (s > e)
    return(vec)
  inside_brackets <- seq(s, e, 2L)
  vec[inside_brackets] <- gsub('\\D*(\\d{4,5})\\D*', '(\\1)', vec[inside_brackets])  
  paste(vec, collapse = '')  
}
fun_1 <- function(string_vec) {
  to_process <- grepl('\\d{4,}', string_vec)
  string_vec[to_process] <- vapply(string_vec[to_process], fun_0, character(1))
  paste(string_vec, collapse = '\n')
}
fun_2 <- function(text) {
    string_list <- strsplit(text, '\n')
    vapply(string_list, fun_1, character(1))
}
```

*Examples*

```
text <- c("1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 (WSO) (89021-design)\nJohn Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)",
          "1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 ASP (890212-wso)\nJohn Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)\nOther Stuff",
          "1110383 Project something SD (890212)\nJohn Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)")
fun_2(text)
# [1] "1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 WSO (89021)\nJohn Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)"                  
# [2] "1110383 Project something 11/22/2019 ASP (89021)2-wso\nJohn Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)\nOther Stuff"
# [3] "1110383 Project something SD (89021)2\nJohn Doe (John.Doe@company22.com)"
```